# Casting Exception for Generic Arrays in Java

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to create a generic Array in Java below the code snippet.

```
static<T extends Comparable<? super T>> T[] exactlyOnce(T[] A){
      T[] temp , B;
      temp = (T[])new Object[A.length];
      B = (T[])new Object[A.length];
   //Rest of the code follows
}
```

It produces following exception not sure on how to resolve this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Comparable;
```

Comment: It needs to be `new Comparable[A.length]`, as the error messsage says.

Comment: @EJP That solved the issue. Thanks